# Handlebars cant select data from json

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

I'm trying to select the title from this JSON:

```
{
    "feed" {
        "title" {
            $t: "animals"
            text: ""
        }
    }
}
```

(This JSON is probably not fully correct, but serves as example. The full JSON can be found [here](https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/104614297509216999699/albumid/5983578789640080817?alt=json))

In my template file, I have this:

```
{{#each feed.title}}
  <h2>{{this}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

While this works, it returns both the text and $t; I only need $t. I've tried to select this in several methods, but it won't work or just returns `[object object]` if I remove the `{#each}` part. So far I've tried:

```
{{#each feed.title.[0]}}, <h2>{{this.[0]}}</h2>, {{#each feed.title.$t}}
```

It's probably something simple, but how do I select just the "Animals" part?

Comment: I don't know handlebars, but my first punt would be '<h2>{{this.$t}}</h2>'

Comment: That returns an empty <h2> :(

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `{{#each feed.title}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following returns the title of the feed

```
 {{feed.title.$t}}
```

I also included a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fju4rzua/1/) with the entire json.

Comment: Weird... sworn i already tried this and it just returned [OBJECT OBJECT]. That's why i used the {{each}}, because that returned the data i needed. 

Perhaps a glitch in my local server, of maybe i made a typo, but this worked. Thanks!